# "[...] você ou Fulano já pensou/pensaram sobre [...]" - concordância verbal

Tags: concordância-verbal

Na frase "Diga-me se você ou Fulano já **pensaram** sobre alternativas caso o salário não seja depositado este mês", é correto utilizar o verbo *pensar* no plural? Como é a concordância de número no caso de um cláusula alternativa como esta?

Comment: Não sei se estou errado, corrijam-me se eu estiver, mas "ou" implica que o orador requer que apenas um dos dois tenha pensado, assim seria "você **ou** Fulano já pens**ou**", já se fosse "e" no lugar do "ou", aí seria "você **e** Fulano já pens**aram**".

Comment: Não, @BrunoLopes, o ou não é necessariamente exclusivo. Podem *ambos* ter pensado no caso, até porque ambos estão interessados em encontrar soluções para o salário [deles] não ser entregue no fim do mês.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neste caso, ambas são possíveis, mas o plural é mais frequente.

Segundo a gramática de Evanildo Bechara, a concordância do verbo com um sujeito ligado por *ou* é feita com o sujeito mais próximo se a conjunção indicar (citando, referências removidas):

> a) *exclusão*:
>       “a quem a doença ou a idade *impossibilitou* de ganharem o
>   sustento...”.
>       Se João Fernandes (ou Platzhoff) os *dá* como entes sem afeições (...)
>
> b) *retificação de número gramatical*:
>       “Cantares é o nome que o autor ou autores do Cancioneiro chamado do Colégio dos Nobres *dão* a cada um dos poemetos...”.
>       Sei que algures *existe* a alma ou as almas, às quais eu me dirijo.
>
> c) *identidade ou equivalência*:
>       O professor ou o nosso segundo pai *merece* o respeito da pátria

Mas:

> Se a ideia expressa pelo predicado puder referir-se a toda a série do
>   sujeito composto, o verbo irá para o plural mais frequentemente, porém
>   pode ocorrer o singular:
>       “A nulidade ou a validade do contrato... *eram* assunto de direito
>   civil”
>       “A ignorância ou errada compreensão da lei não *eximem* de pena
>   (...)”
>       “Mas aí, como se o destino ou o acaso, ou o que quer que fosse se *lembrasse* de dar algum pasto aos meus arrombos possessórios

Parece-me que é este o caso aplicável à frase que dás. É uma questão de interpretação, mas não me parece que exista nenhuma noção de exclusão. Na verdade, *ou* podia ser substituído por *e* sem que o significado mudasse.

Comment: Pergunto-me se a opção pelo singular ou plural não condiciona a interpretação do sujeito. Por exemplo, o singular no último exemplo, «destino ou o acaso...», leva-me a pensar que o agente é só um deles e e não todos simultaneamente.

Comment: +1.  Eu raramente uso o plural quando a conjunção usada é "ou".  "A nulidade ou validade do contrato **é** assunto a ser discutido em uma reunião."

Comment: No primeiro exemplo de a), o sujeito não é a doença? As pessoas impossibilitadas seriam o objeto direto.

Comment: @ANeves O sujeito é "a doença ou a ideia".

Comment: Ah, sim, obrigado, «a doença ou a idade». Assim faz sentido isso ser um exemplo.

Comment: Realmente a intenção é do quarto caso, onde quer-se saber se um dos dois ou ambos pensaram sobre...